# Cannot find hostname option in Mesibo On Premise Configuration

Tags: mesibo

The tutorial for a clone messenger app states that a hostname for the On Premise server should be specified:
[image: hostname]

But in my Mesibo console, the option to enter a hostname is not there:

[image: hostname missing]

Hence I am getting an error(Or atleast im assuming its becase of that):
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGtkU.png)

> E0608-131427-190 (1): Unable to open /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
> (truncate 1) E0608-131427-191 (1): starting mesibo E0608-131427-191
> (1): PID: 1 E0608-131427-193 (1): build date: Tue Jul 28 15:17:28 2020
> UTC E0608-131427-193 (1): build number: 2591 E0608-131427-193 (1):
> module_exports_init E0608-131427-193 (1): Local IP count: 2
> E0608-131427-193 (1): --> multiple(2) IPs found - listening on all the
> IPs. If you like to use particular IPs only, set them in configuration
> using one or more 'ip' fields E0608-131427-200 (1): signal ignored: 17
> E0608-131427-200 (1): Local IP Address: 172.31.46.94 E0608-131427-200
> (1): Local IP Address: 172.17.0.1 E0608-131427-568 (12):
> ***************** ERROR *****************
>
> ==> Missing Configuration - go to Mesibo console and enter on-premise configuration
>
> E0608-131427-569 (12): on termination: 15 E0608-131427-569 (12):
> onexit called: 1 0 E0608-131427-569 (12): Deleting all users and
> saving notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hostname in the console now, so ignore that part in the tutorial and configure the rest of the fields. The latest mesibo version is allowing you to configure it from the command line and it is optional.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/#command-line-arguments

Comment: Thank you for your timely response. Solved but im now getting an error, Invalid app token.

Comment: The save button in the console is also permanently disabled.

Comment: You might want to hard reload the console. Most likely that your browser has cached the older version of the console javascript file which is expecting hostname parameter.  Regarding the app token, verify the token in console or else file a ticket on the mesibo website since you can't share your token here.